# Need help finding old deleted question

Tags: support

I wrote a question, and later provided my own answer. I spent a decent amount of time writing up that answer and I would like to have it for my notes, but it seems like it was deleted at some point.

It was a question about how photons can be expressed in a cavity using the transmission function of a cavity (verses solving with the input-output formalism).

Any ideas how I can find this? (I think it was likely deleted more than 60 days ago, although I'd guess I wrote the question some time in the last 6 months.) I'm not so interested in fighting some moderator about whether it should've been deleted, I'd just like to get that answer back for my own reference.

Comment: See John's answer for the actual answer, but you're likely talking about [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589734/50583)

Comment: Oh great, thanks!

Comment: If the post has been voted on, your could find it via your [reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers)? You will need a moderator to find the question for you since your rep is under 10K.